# What is the process by which a question is marked as duplicate by Community♦?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, community-user

For example https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77966/121 was:

> marked as duplicate by Jens, bbgodfrey, Community♦ 10 hours ago

Neither Jens nor bbgodfrey hold a Gold tag badge applicable to this question.
Why were only two close votes needed and why did Community♦ get involved?

Comment: If I didn't have the dupe hammer, you could have seen it in action right here on this very question. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Indeed.  Thanks.

Comment: Anyway to save people the need to click: this means the question author aka OP agreed with a pending dupe close vote, thus causing insta-close following a recent change. (more details in the dupe)