# Can we make it clear that there is a tooltip hidden behind certain text?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, tooltips

Tooltips seem to be pretty important on Stack Exchange. And it seems a lot of them get missed.

For example, the new [mark your own question as dupe 'thing'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate) lead to 2 questions being asked about that ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251905/what-is-the-process-by-which-a-question-is-marked-as-duplicate-by-community%E2%99%A6) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253016/why-does-community-user-vote-to-close-a-question?lq=1)) - these wouldn't have been asked had it been clear there was a tooltip on the 'Community' user's link under the question. *We* know about this 'new' feature, but **do new users know that**? Probably not. (In case you have no idea what tooltip I'm talking about, rollover Community [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254044/someone-killed-chat)):

[image]

Now, I'm not saying asking questions is a bad thing, but it does waste time for the asker and the dupe-marker, when all they really have to do is roll-over some text to get a pretty clear explanation.

**Another example**: all dates on SE have a tooltip saying their exact date and time that action happened - *we* know that, but **do new users know that**? Probably not.

**Another example**: Do you know how to see **when** a post you flagged was *marked helpful*? Did you find out by accident or did you think it was obvious? If it was the former, then this proposal will really help!

[image]

**Another example**: How do you find out the exact number of badges earned for a specific badge from the [Badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges)? Did you find out by accident or did you think it was obvious? If it was the former, then this proposal will really help!

**Another example**: How do you find out when a post was made community wiki without having to go to the posts' revisions?

[image]

---

**What I propose**

I recently asked a [question on UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76152/how-do-you-make-sure-users-know-that-there-is-a-tooltip-attached-to-something) about how to tell people there is a tooltip somewhere for use on one of my websites, but I think the answers there are completely useable in SE!

**Can we add a dotted underline under (important) text where there is a tooltip?** This is pretty standard thing - sites use it to indicate rollover text on places. What's the point of having tooltips if their existence is unknown?

I think it will really help new users and existing users to find out things really easily and quickly. We could also change the cursor to a `?` on hover (along with the dotted line) if you wanted to stretch it!

Here's what it would look like:

[image]

Comment: It'd look less ugly! :D But you forgot to mention all the per site meta questions about community's dupe vote.

Comment: This looks too much like ad words, people would expect advertisement to pop up when hovering thus won't do it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard but ad words are generally fully underlined right? this is dotted!! Anyway - this is simple the option I thought was the best - there are many more options (see my linked UX question)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ not sure, but many won't notice the difference. :/

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ some ad words are underlined with dotted too... (or worse, dotted + **double underline**). Underline is also usually related to a link (no matter if it's dotted or not). Not saying that the feature request itself is bad, but still not sure how to make it appear clear but non-obstructing. I was just thinking of having a <sup>?</sup> that can be hovered at the end of the phrase (concept from Wikipedia's footnote), but is it clear enough?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeah - like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/swrvo.png)? Not a bad option either (I got the screenshot from the linked UX.SE question)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Depends on your browser; Gecko browsers use dotted underlines for `<abbr>` elements by default, so that would easily get the message across to those users. And I suspect most users are well aware already that SE is far above the sort of atrocious scumsuckery that in-text adwords represent.

Comment: Thanks @cat! Hope this gets seen! :D

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I didn't know about a lot of the tooltips you mentioned in this question, which makes me want this even more. :D

Comment: @cat hmmmm guess what I'm thinking now ;)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It's like you have nothing better to do all day than write handy little userscripts to fix SE's *majorly annoying UX issues* :P