# After handling a chat flag, tooltip claims I flagged the message

Tags: bug, chat, tooltips, chat-flags

This is the tooltip I see for a chat message with a flag that I handled:

> [image]

I never flagged it myself, and chose "not sure" as handle action. Can the tooltip please be fixed?

Comment: I flag the complete room as offensive...

Comment: @rene but... but... icecream! :D

Comment: Meh... Who [knows about tooltips?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254049/can-we-make-it-clear-that-there-is-a-tooltip-hidden-behind-certain-text) :P (+1 though :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ well, the flag was red in the beginning that is why I hovered.

Comment: Hmmmm... Good! SE understands!